# Configuring Getty for hardware terminal

Tags: terminal, serial-console, getty

I am looking to configure a serial line for the following:

```
9600 Baud
Word Length: 8BIT
Parity: Mark 
XON/XOFF On
```

I can't seem to locate the details on the "Parity Mark" part so far on my searches on google. I am trying to get a vm to allocate a hardware terminal, and if I setup the terminal using hyperterm first, then launch the VM it works fine, otherwise, no go. My aim is to move this from a VM to real hardware at some point where hyperterm is not an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The source-code for `agetty` shows [this chunk](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/agetty.c#L416) related to *autobaud*:

```
/* Optionally detect the baud rate from the modem status message. */
debug("before autobaud\n");
if (serial_tty_option(&options, F_PARSE))
    auto_baud(&termios);
```

and the `F_PARSE` option is [set here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/agetty.c#L725):

```
    case 'm':
        op->flags |= F_PARSE;
        break;
```

which corresponds to the `-m` (`--extract-baud`) feature of `agetty` (see [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html)).

The manual page notes

> Since the `-m` feature may fail on heavily-loaded  systems,  you
>   still  should  enable  BREAK  processing  by  enumerating  all
>   expected baud rates on the command line.

that is, you should have "`-m 9600`" on the getty line to get the autobaud or 9600 baud feature.

The details on `mark parity` are (agreed) harder to find.  *[Linux and MARK/SPACE Parity](https://viereck.ch/linux-mark-space-parity/)* by Thomas Lochmatter says that

- 8M1 (8 data bits, MARK parity, 1 stop bit) can be emulated with 8N2
- 8S1 (8 data bits, SPACE parity, 1 stop bit) can be emulated in two ways (and goes on to outline a solution)

Finally (back to the manual for `agetty`) regarding XON/XOFF:

> **`-h`**, **`--flow-control`**
>   Enable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control. It is left up  to  the
>   application to disable software (XON/XOFF) flow protocol where
>   appropriate.

Just to clarify, `agetty` developers expect that XON/XOFF are set in the terminal I/O (see [`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)) after making a connection rather than in via `getty`.